# `flex-basis: auto` sizes parent as if child were `flex-basis: auto`, when child is `flex-basis:10px`

Tags: html, flexbox

For example, you shouldn't be able to see the red of the parent here, but you do, because `parent: 0 0 auto` is sizing the parent to the auto width of its child content. You can see clearly though, the real width of its content is 10px, so shouldn't its auto sizing make the parent 10px as well?

```css
body{
  display:flex;
}

#parent {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}

#child {
  flex: 0 0 10px;
  background-color: grey;
}


div{ display:flex; min-width:0; min-height:0; overflow:hidden; } /*There's some weirdness described here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-doesnt-flex-item-shrink-past-content-size where flex elements default to min-width:auto, which could have caused problems here, but this doesn't change anything, so apparently this is not the issue*/
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">childcontents</div>
</div>
```

This occurs in firefox and chrome, so presumably this is going to turn out to be *correct* somehow. I'd like to know how, so that I can stop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my understanding of the spec, this is a bug.

What Michael_B said is correct, first `#parent` is sized, and once its width is know, `#child` can flex. Since flexing usually involves growing or shrinking, the size of the flex container must be known before flexing the flex item; and the final size of the flex item may not be the flex basis, so the flex container shouldn't be sized using that value.

The solution is easy: use `width` instead of `flex-basis`. `width` does not flex, so it doesn't depend on the width of the container. Thus the container can use the `width` of their contents when sized.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}
#parent {
  flex: none;
  background-color: red;
}
#child {
  width: 10px;
  flex: none;
  background-color: grey;
}
div {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">childcontents</div>
</div>
```

That said, **in your case using `flex-basis` should work**. That's because your flex item has both a zero flex grow factor and a zero flex shrink factor. It cannot grow nor shrink, it becomes directly frozen. Therefore it's possible to use consider the `flex-basis` when sizing the parent, and the spec says so:

> [**9.9.3. Flex Item Intrinsic Size Contributions**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#intrinsic-item-contributions)
>
> The main-size [min-content](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#min-content-contribution)/[max-content contribution](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#max-content-contribution) of a
>   [flex item](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) is its *outer* [min-content](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#min-content)/[max-content size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#max-content),
>   clamped by its [flex base size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-base-size) as a maximum (if it is not
>   growable) and/or as a minimum (if it is not shrinkable), and then
>   further clamped by its [min](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-size-property)/[max main size properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-size-property).

The contribution of the ungrowable unshrinkable flex item is clamped by its flex base size both as a maximum and as a minimum. That is, the contribution is exactly the flex base size, which is defined as the flex basis when the flex basis is definite.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the flex layout algorithm calculates the width of the flex container *before* arriving at the width of the flex items.

Hence, it determines the `auto` size of `#parent` based on the full width of `#child`.

Then it sizes `#child` to `flex-basis: 10px`.

At his point, however, the `auto` width of the parent has already been determined and is inflexible.

Testing in Chrome, re-arranging the rules makes no difference, so it doesn't appear to be a cascading issue.

This is my view of the behavior without an official reference to back it up. You may find the precise answer here: [**W3C Spec: Flex Layout Algorithm**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#layout-algorithm)